# How to put my videos into a dropdown menu with my current code?

Tags: html

here's my current code:

```
  <div  style="width: 640px; height: 480px; position: relative;">

  <iframe src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/LINKTOMYFILE/preview"   width="640" height="480" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" seamless=""></iframe>

  <div style="width: 80px; height: 80px; position: absolute; opacity: 0; right: 0px; top: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
  </div>
```

How can I wrap this into this kind of dropdown menu?

```
<p style="text-align: center;"><select style="margin: 5px auto; width: 146px;" onchange="document.getElementById('11qq').src=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
<option value="VIDEOLINK1">Video1</option>
<option value="VIDEOLINK2">Video2</option>

</select></p>
<p style="text-align: center;"><iframe id="11qq" src="START VIDEO" width="960" height="540" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe></p>
```

I tried a few variants now but none seem to work. Is it even possible?

Cheers

Comment: In what way does your code fail?  What does it do?  What are you expecting it to do?  Why?

Comment: `How can I wrap this...` what is `this`? Do you mean you want the video to be actually in the dropdown?